# Error of a mean of data

Tags: statistics

I am taking the mean of a set of data, each with their own error. I would like to know what the error is for that value. Not the uncertainty of the mean, but the uncertainty of the measurement, if that makes any sense.

Comment: Use the mean of the errors if you don't have more information about the distribution of the measure

Comment: So if I knew that the distribution of error was a specific distribution, I could calculate the mean of the errors in the same way that I would if they were values instead of errors?

Comment: If you knew the distribution of the measure you could better combine the uncertainities: imagine a measure that can only be positive, taking the mean of the errors could lead you to a measure range including negative values (in extremes cases).

Comment: But if every measurement was off by say, plus or minus 1 mm, the error of the mean would just be 1 mm (not knowing the distribution of error)

Comment: If we are measuring centimeters I don't see any problem.